# Pub/Sub message to multiple BigQuery records

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am a **total** newbie to Apache Beam and Dataflow, so I'm sorry if this question is too basic  or is already answered on the documentation (I've already looked and didn't find anything that suits me).

I have some IoT devices that are pushing data to IoT Core → Pub/Sub, and then I have a Dataflow worker processing that topic and pushing the data to Big Query. So far, it works OK (I'm using the Google-provided template, so it's supposed to work OK).

Due to bandwidth constraints, we can't push 10 messages per second from the IoT device, but we can combine all 10 readings into one message and send that every second.

The current message has a structure like this:

```json
{
    "field1": 32,
    "field2": 4.6,
    ...
    "fieldN": "something"
}
```

And it's being properly written to BigQuery. Now I want to send the data with this structure

```json
[
    {
        "field1": 32,
        "field2": 4.6,
        ...
        "fieldN": "something"
    },
    {
        "field1": 32,
        "field2": 4.6,
        ...
        "fieldN": "something"
    },
    ...
    {
        "field1": 32,
        "field2": 4.6,
        ...
        "fieldN": "something"
    }
]
```

And a worker to iterate over the message's data and write multiple records to Big Query instead of one.

1. Is there a template to do this, or should I create my own worker?
2. If I have to create my own, can I test it locally? I've read that python doesn't support streaming data for Apache Beam (though all the answers I read were 4+ years old)

I'd appreciate some documentation or guide on how to build what I need.

Answer (score 1):

In a Beam transform, split your message coming from the source PCollection and create several new messages in the output PCollection.

Then, continue your pipeline up to BigQuery

Comment: I'm a total noob in this. Could you please point me to a python template that I can modify?

Comment: See FlatMap: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/flatmap/